# How to Apply Databind For Instant Update

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

How to apply databind, so that the recent updated value will be displyed instantly, as i press update button ?

```
Dim cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
Dim con As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(constr)
Try
    Dim strSql As String = "UPDATE a1_admins SET ImageURL = '" _
    & "~/admin/Image/" & FileName & "' WHERE EmployeeId =" _
    & Label1.Text

    '------------"
    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = strSql
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
    Response.Write(ex.Message)
Finally
    cmd.Dispose()
    con.Dispose()
End Try
```

Comment: **YIKES!!** SQL Injection alert !! ....

Comment: This is just the `UPDATE` statement that updates your underlying table. You would have to have a second SQL statement (preferably a **parametrized** one!) that will then go fetch the data so that you get something back that you can then databind to some UI piece

Comment: Ya i have select query also !

Comment: Please tell me in which English dictionary is 'Whatz' a word?

Comment: @m.edmondson: your not "l33t" enough to have access to that. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just re-databind your control.  If you post your databinding code I can provide a better answer.